# Access denied for database user message on production

Tags: database

Our live D7 site suddenly created the white screen of death, followed by an access denied message for the drupal database user.

I was creating a new database for another version of the website in a different docroot, something I've done in the past with no problems. When that install didn't go well, I granted permissions to the new database to the same user as our live site.

I'm not sure why that had an effect on the live site or how to fix it. A MySQL query still shows that the drupal database user still has privileges:

```
SHOW GRANTS for 'dbuser';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `drupal`.* TO 'dbuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: Is the settings.php db info correct for production?

Comment: Yes. I found out that I granted all privileges as @'localhost' on the new database instead of as @'%' and it somehow caused dbuser to access the existing drupal site as @'localhost' also. Once I granted as @'%' it came back up... I also found that there was no password for 'dbuser'@'localhost'. Confusing stuff.

Comment: Should I use the same user or a different user for a different drupal database on the same server?

Comment: It's been a while since I have set it up manually, but usually each server is isolated with its own database and users. I mainly host on acquia so it's all automatic through a server side settings include.

Comment: It is best practice to isolate different databases for your Drupal websites as Kevin states above. When I set up different environments I create seperate databases with own dedictated users. Should your site get hacked and settings.php is compromised the hackers can only access 1 database.